# how to save 'srsName' when exporting (OpenLayers) to GML?

Tags: format, openlayers

I export the layer to GML, and get string. But there is no 'srsName'.

```
var my_layer = boxLayer;
if (my_layer instanceof OpenLayers.Layer.Vector && my_layer.features.length == 0)
      {
        console.log('Object not ready :( ')
        return;
      }
    console.log('projection (srsName) =', my_layer.features[0].layer.projection.getCode());//"EPSG:3857"
    layer['format'] = new OpenLayers.Format.GML();
    console.log('OpenLayers.Format.GML:\n ',my_layer.format.write(my_layer.features[0]));//GML string without srsName
```

What am i doing wrong?